# war not properly deployed with tomcat and maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat7

Hi I'm developing an application using spring and hibernate I'm deploying the war on tomcat with maven everything works fine on the first deploy with

```
 mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

but the problem comes when I deploy on second time I find only the WEB-INF directory [image]

any ideas

Answer (score 0):

First perform clean then run deploy and also prefer cold deployment procedure

Comment: I tried mvn clean then deploy but not working. Sorry But I don't understand the term cold deployment

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this actually before redeploying you have to use

```
mvn tomcat7:undeploy
```

the war and the web app will be totally be removed from tomcat

then

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

et voilà